# Cross opening URLs between computer and mobile phone?

Tags: macos, ios, url

I am looking for a solution that would allow me to cross-open an URL between computer (OS X) and phone (iPhone).

Here is the use case: using the iphone to barcode scan an QR code that opens an URL but I do want to open this URL on the computer, not on the phone.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable iCloud and use the [iCloud tabs](http://www.apple.com/safari/#gallery-icloud-tabs) feature of Safari. On all the connected devices you will see the open tabs of the others.

[image]

See *[Set up and use iCloud Tabs](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5372?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)*

Comment: Firefox has a similar feature that works cross-platform, for people with Android phones, say. You must login to Firefox on the browsers (one time only) and select "Send Tab to Devices".